# Trouble saving and displaying the key and value pairs in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage, sessionstorage

Okay so I have been working on this code forever and I still cant get it to work right. I'm having two issues with my code.

1. I'm trying to save the values for each input and select field and display them again when the page is refreshed.
2. Every time a user types into the same input field a new `key: value` pair is created. I just want the same input field the user is typing into to update the `sessionStorage`in real time when the user changes its value.

If it helps I'm using JQuery and PHP. My JQuery code is located below

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 5;
    var x = 1;

    if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined'){
        $('.worker').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            if(x < max_fields){
                x++;

                $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').append('<input type="text" name="first_name[]" class="first-name" /><input type="text" name="last_name[]" class="last-name" /><select name="title[]" class="title"><option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Worker">Worker</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option></select>');

                sessionStorage.setItem('Data',$(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').html());
            }
        });

        if(sessionStorage.getItem('Data')){
            $('.worker').closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').html(sessionStorage.getItem('Data')); 
        }
    }
}); 


var worker_record = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.worker').closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').on('input', function(){
        var fname = $('.first-name').val();
        var lname = $('.last-name').val();
        var wtitle = $('.title').val();
        var worker_data = {first_name: fname, last_name: lname, title: wtitle};
        worker_record.push(worker_data);
        for(var i=0; i<worker_record.length; i++){
            sessionStorage.newWorker = JSON.stringify(worker_record);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="worker-container">
            <label class="worker-label"><input type="text" name="first_name[]" class="first-name" /></label>
        </div>

        <div class="worker-container">
            <label class="worker-label"><input type="text" name="last_name[]" class="last-name" /></label>
        </div>

        <div class="worker-container-last">
            <label class="worker-label">
                <select name="title[]" class="title">
                    <option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option>
                    <option value="Boss">Boss</option>
                    <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
                    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="add-more"></div>
        <div><a class="worker" href="">Add Another Worker</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qjp6uscu/

Answer (score 2):

**For Issue #2**

You can get the existing sessionStorage key using the `getItem` method like this,

```
  var worker_record = sessionStorage.getItem('newWorker');
```

If it doesn't exist initialize an empty array, else parse it.

```
  if (!worker_record ) { 
    worker_record = [];
  } else {
    worker_record = JSON.parse(worker_record);
  }
```

Push your worker_data into session storage,

```
  worker_record.push(worker_data);
```

Use the `setItem` method to set the updated key/value like this,

```
  sessionStorage.setItem('newWorker', JSON.stringify(worker_record));
```

Comment: Where do I exactly replace and place the new code? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can have it in your `(document).ready(function(){....})` block where you have already written the logic.

Comment: Can you open up your DevTools in chrome and can you check whether your variables/values are appearing under `Resources` => `Session Storage` ?

Comment: They are not appearing at all

Comment: Revert your code back to your old state, run it afresh and repeat the above steps and then check.

Comment: Still not appearing.

Comment: Can you move your `var worker_record=[];` inside your `(document).ready()` function and check?

Comment: There is still nothing.

Comment: Okay. Can you please put your working code in a JSFiddle and share me a link to debug the same?

Comment: I have corrected the errors and updated the fiddle, check it out here.. https://jsfiddle.net/qjp6uscu/2/